# beforecopy event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

If you go to the Google Chrome developer tools then **Scripts > Event Listener Breakpoints > Clipboard** you will find the event *beforecopy*. Two questions:

1) What is it?

2) Why is it useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Occurs before the selection is copied to the clipboard and before the
>   [oncopy](http://oncopy) event.
>
> - In Internet Explorer, the `onbeforecopy` event occurs on the deepest
>     element in the DOM hierarchy that contains the entire selection.
> - In Google Chrome and Safari, the `onbeforecopy` event occurs on the
>     deepest element in the DOM hierarchy that contains the start point of
>     the selection.

The `beforecopy` event is supported by Internet Explorer and WebKit browsers (Safari and Chrome).

http://help.dottoro.com/ljrlxaae.php and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Microsoft-specific_events).

Comment: It also bizarrely fires (along with `beforepaste` and `beforecut`) when you bring up the context menu by right-clicking, regardless of whether you later click on any of the menu items. http://jsfiddle.net/9kYwu/

Comment: @TimDown, that's what makes it a "before" event.

Comment: @PaulDraper why would a `beforecopy` event fire before _cut?_

Answer (score 1):

This is occurring before items are sent to the clipboard.

This is useful for sites that add their own footer, e.g. CNET adds the article at the end.  Or places that want to transform the URL's.  It just allows for more granular control.